# Find files modified today, using command line (bash)

Tags: bash

As we all know, despite being named "Finder", the Finder is virtually useless at finding files.

In Mac OS X 10.6 (or any version), how can I use the command line (bash in Terminal) to find files modified today?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are several ways to do this in bash from the terminal - depending on exactly what you want to find:

Find files modified in the last 24 hours

```
find / -mtime -1 -print
```

Find files modified today (likely what you want)

```
find / -newerct 'yesterday' -print
```

or, using Spotlight

```
mdfind date:today
```

This can also be done from the GUI with Spotlight.

1. Open Spotlight (option-command space by default).
2. Add a criteria to search for, by hitting the Plus sign near the top
   right of the Spotlight window.
3. Change the criteria to "Last modified date" is "today."

Comment: Note that you don't need the `-print` at the end since `find` defaults to it and in most cases you want to replace the `/` with either `.` to find down from the current directory or `~` to find in your home directory rather than the top of the tree.

Comment: possible to check files modifies in last 5 minutes or last 2 hours?

Comment: @Ewoks Yes, `mtime` defaults to using days, but if you specify units, can find modifications from last n seconds, minutes, hours, or weeks, e.g.:

    `find . -mtime -5m` -or-
    `find . -mtime -2h`

Comment: Just to help others -Btime is creation time, -atime is access time, -ctime is change of file status (aka "date added"), -mtime is modified time